# Plot a 3-D column plot in Gnuplot (5.3 development version) with "variable" boxdepth (to appear fixed width) columns on logscaled y,z-axes

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to plot a 3-D column plot in Gnuplot 5.3 (development version) on y,z-logscales such that the columns appear uniform in size on the graph (i.e., variable "boxdepth" for each point depending on position)

It seems as though boxwidth can be set for each point in the 4th column, but not for boxdepth?

```
set grid nopolar
set grid xtics nomxtics ytics nomytics ztics nomztics nortics nomrtics \
 nox2tics nomx2tics noy2tics nomy2tics nocbtics nomcbtics
set grid lw 1
set xyplane 0
set xlabel 'Year' offset 12,-3,0 font ",16"
set ylabel 'traj length (ns,{/Symbol m}s,ms)' offset -12,-3,0 font ",16"
set zlabel 'M of atoms' offset -3,0,0 font ",16"
set xtics offset 2,0,-2 font ",16"
set ytics ("1 ns" 1, "10" 10, "100" 100, "1 {/Symbol m}s" 1000, "10" 10000, "100" 100000, "1 ms" 1000000)
set ytics offset -1,-1,0 font ",16" #format "1E{%T}" #format "%.0s*10^{%T}"
set ztics font ",16"
set xrange[1995:2020]
set yrange[0.05:2e6]
set zrange[0.01:1e3]
set logscale yz
set style data lines
set boxwidth 0.3 relative
set boxdepth 0
set grid vertical layerdefault   lt 0 linecolor 0 linewidth 1.000,  lt 0 linecolor 0 linewidth 1.000
set pm3d depthorder base
set pm3d interpolate 1,1 flush begin noftriangles border lt black linewidth 1.000 dashtype solid corners2color mean
set view 60,300
splot 'nano.dat' u 1:2:3 w boxes,'micro.dat' u 1:2:3 w boxes lc 3,'milli.dat' u 1:2:3 w boxes lc rgb 'red' lw 4
```

Comment: Update: As of yesterday (23 May 2019) both boxwidth and boxdepth behave sensibly for 3D boxes with logscaled x and/or y axes.

Answer (score 0):

gnuplot development version 23-May-2019

git head 6edcb769

```
# 
# initial setup as in boxes3d.dem
# 

set xrange [.5:12]
set yrange [.5:6]
set boxwidth .05
set boxdepth .05
set log xy
set tics nolog
set xtics 1
set ytics 1
set ztics 5
splot for [col=1:5] \
   'candlesticks.dat' using 1:(col):(col*column(col)):(rgbfudge($1)) with boxes fc rgb variable
```

[image]